# Reference a question (exercise package)

Tags: cross-referencing, exercises

I am using the package 'exercise' and I want to reference a question and a question later in the text. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}

    \Question{This is a question}
        \subQuestion{this is a subquestion}

    \Question{Reference question 1 here}
        \subQuestion{Reference subquestion 1.a here}

\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `\label` - `\ref` - mechanism, i.e. `\label{foo}` and `\ref{foo}` at the required places and compile twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\renewcommand{\thesubQuestion}{\theQuestion.\alph{subQuestion}}
\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}

    \Question{This is a question} \label{foo}
        \subQuestion{this is a subquestion} \label{foobar}

    \Question{Reference question \ref{foo} here}
        \subQuestion{Reference subquestion \ref{foobar} here}

\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]